# Уменьшить код JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let colorsIn = document.getElementsByClassName('clrB');
let body = document.querySelector('body')

let colors = ['red', 'blue', 'pink', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'salmon', 'sienna'];
let i = 0;
colorsIn[0].onmousedown = function() {
  if (i == 1) body.style.background = colors[0];
  i = 1;
}
colorsIn[1].onmousedown = function() {
  if (i == 1) body.style.background = colors[1];
  i = 1;
}
colorsIn[2].onmousedown = function() {
  if (i == 1) body.style.background = colors[2];
  i = 1;
}
colorsIn[3].onmousedown = function() {
  if (i == 1) body.style.background = colors[3];
  i = 1;
}
colorsIn[4].onmousedown = function() {
  if (i == 1) body.style.background = colors[4];
  i = 1;
}
colorsIn[5].onmousedown = function() {
  if (i == 1) body.style.background = colors[5];
  i = 1;
}
colorsIn[6].onmousedown = function() {
  if (i == 1) body.style.background = colors[6];
  i = 1;
}
colorsIn[7].onmousedown = function() {
  if (i == 1) body.style.background = colors[7];
  i = 1;
}
colorsIn[8].onmousedown = function() {
  if (i == 1) body.style.background = colors[8];
  i = 1;
}
```

```css
.colors {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.clrB {
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
  display: flex;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
}

.color1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.color2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.color3 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.color4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.color5 {
  background-color: green;
}

.color6 {
  background-color: purple;
}

.color7 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.color8 {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.color9 {
  background-color: sienna;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
        <div class="color1 clrB"></div>
        <div class="color2 clrB"></div>
        <div class="color3 clrB"></div>
        <div class="color4 clrB"></div>
        <div class="color5 clrB"></div>
        <div class="color6 clrB"></div>
        <div class="color7 clrB"></div>
        <div class="color8 clrB"></div>
        <div class="color9 clrB"></div>
    </div>
```

Есть данный код, мне нужно уменьшить его(сделать цикл, например). Прошу не гнобить меня за код, я в JS не так давно.

Comment: В чем заключается суть вопроса?

Comment: надо использовать цикл

Comment: @Leks ну и как его написать? Все, что я пробовал не работало

Comment: @Leks, зачем цикл?)

Comment: @Qwertiy как я понял надо перебрать потому цикл Ваш код мне нравится больше

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.colors').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('clrB')) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = getComputedStyle(e.target).backgroundColor
  }
})
```

```css
.colors {
  width: 174px;
  height: 174px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.clrB {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
}

.color1 { background-color: red;    }
.color2 { background-color: blue;   }
.color3 { background-color: pink;   }
.color4 { background-color: yellow; }
.color5 { background-color: green;  }
.color6 { background-color: purple; }
.color7 { background-color: orange; }
.color8 { background-color: salmon; }
.color9 { background-color: sienna; }
```

```html
<div class="colors">
  <div class="color1 clrB"></div>
  <div class="color2 clrB"></div>
  <div class="color3 clrB"></div>
  <div class="color4 clrB"></div>
  <div class="color5 clrB"></div>
  <div class="color6 clrB"></div>
  <div class="color7 clrB"></div>
  <div class="color8 clrB"></div>
  <div class="color9 clrB"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
let colors = ['red', 'blue', 'pink', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'salmon', 'sienna'];

let clrB = document.querySelectorAll('.clrB');

for( let i = 0; i < clrB.length; i++ ){
  clrB[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  })
}
```

```css
.colors {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  .clrB {
    width: 33%;
    height: 33%;
    display: flex;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    /* border-collapse: collapse; */
  }

  .color1 {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .color2 {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .color3 {
    background-color: pink;
  }

  .color4 {
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .color5 {
    background-color: green;
  }

  .color6 {
    background-color: purple;
  }

  .color7 {
    background-color: orange;
  }

  .color8 {
    background-color: salmon;
  }

  .color9 {
    background-color: sienna;
  }
```

```html
<div class="colors">
    <div class="color1 clrB"></div>
    <div class="color2 clrB"></div>
    <div class="color3 clrB"></div>
    <div class="color4 clrB"></div>
    <div class="color5 clrB"></div>
    <div class="color6 clrB"></div>
    <div class="color7 clrB"></div>
    <div class="color8 clrB"></div>
    <div class="color9 clrB"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Темный Маг как-то так

Comment: Поздравляю с первой тысячей! Так держать в океане знаний

Comment: @ Alexandr_TT обнял, приподнял, покружил ٩(◕‿◕｡)۶